# Can I connect to multiple audio input devices using MediaDevices.getUserMedia() for a webrtc stream?

Tags: audio, video-streaming, webrtc, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I haven't found any support for this in the `getUserMedia` docs. If I can only request a single audio device via constraints, I'm wondering if it's possible to call `getUserMedia` again for the second audio device, then merge/combine the resulting streams into one so I can attach it to a single audio/video element.

My end goal is to set up a webrtc stream that consists of video and 2 audio input devices. I already have a webrtc stream setup with video and a single audio input device working, I am just looking to merge in an additional audio stream. I mention this in case there is some option for this on the webrtc side as well.

With all of that said, if there *is* a solution for combining streams, will there be a concern for keeping the audio in sync?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up creating this function to accomplish the stream merging:

```
function createMergedStream(...streams: MediaStream[]): MediaStream {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext()

    const audioSources: MediaStreamAudioSourceNode[] = []
    const videoTracks: MediaStreamTrack[] = []

    streams.forEach((stream) => {
        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            if (track.kind === "video") {
                videoTracks.push(track)
            }
        })
        audioSources.push(audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream))
    })

    const destination = audioContext["createMediaStreamDestination"]()
    audioSources.forEach((audioSource) => {
        audioSource.connect(destination)
    })

    videoTracks.forEach((track) => {
        destination.stream.addTrack(track)
    })

    return destination.stream
}
```

Turns out the client was actually looking to access multiple channels from a multi-channel audio interface, so I have some more digging to do. Figured I'd shared this code regardless, in case someone ever stumbles across this post.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is ask for the mediastream of the audio1 and video1. Then the mediastream of audio2. Take the tracks of stream2 with `let track = stream2.getTracks()[0]` and add this track to stream1 with `stream1.addTrack(track)`. Stream1 then contains all the tracks you need. [addTrack function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack)

Answer (score 0):

a stream with more than a single audio and/or video track isn't useful since only the first track will be played. You can however transmit two streams and play them in separate video elements.

If you want to mix audio, webaudio enables that.